# Turning a string into a list with specifications

Tags: python, string, list

I want to create a list out of my string in python that would show me how many times a letter is shown in a row inside the string.
for example:

```
my_string= "google"
```

i want to create a list that looks like this:

```
[['g', 1], ['o', 2], ['g', 1], ['l', 1], ['e', 1]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried so far? SO is not a homework or code assignment writing site, we help you with concrete problems with your code instead.

Comment: Try looking up run length encoding. Say: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Python

Comment: @MartijnPieters: sure it is. Just scroll down a bit.

Comment: @thg435: Yup, there will always be someone to jump in and try and engineer an answer anyway. Still, this question deserves to be closed as NARQ.

Comment: hi... i'm sorry if I didn't ask correctly. This is my first time here and yes it is my homework but I'm really trying to learn from you guys... This is what I did so far: my_string = "google" for letter in my_string:
 string_list= [letter, my_string.count(letter)]
 print string_list,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import groupby
my_string= "google"
[(c, len(list(i))) for c, i in groupby(my_string)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression and a dictionary to find and store the longest string of each letter like this

```
s = 'google'
nodubs = [s[0]] + [s[x] if s[x-1] != s[x] else '' for x in range(1,len(s))]
nodubs = ''.join(nodubs)
import re
dic = {}
for letter in set(s):
    matches = re.findall('%s+' % letter, s)
    longest = max([len(x) for x in matches])
    dic[letter] = longest

print [[n,dic[n]] for n in nodubs]
```

Result:

```
[['g', 1], ['o', 2], ['g', 1], ['l', 1], ['e', 1]]
```